# What is the maximum negative output voltage of an emitter follower with a split +10v/-10v supply?

Tags: voltage

I'm perplexed by a passage in Horowitz and Hill's "Art of Electronics" (1st ed., p. 54).  They present the reader with a simple emitter follower circuit.  The input voltage is a 10v amplitude sine-wave.  The transistor itself is fed +10v directly to the collector.  There is a 1k resistor on the emitter, which is supplied with -10v.  According to the authors, the sine wave input will be preserved at the output.  The positive peak will look just like the input at almost full amplitude but the negative peak will clip at -4.4v.  I can't for the life of me figure out where they got -4.4v.  If the power supply is split +10/-10v, wouldn't the output clip at -10v, not -4.4v like the text says?

I tested the circuit on EveryCircuit and the output clipped as expected at -10v.  Here is the circuit I built to try to figure this out for any EveryCircuit users.
http://everycircuit.com/circuit/6493906064375808
I'm a novice here, and having an impossible time figuring out if I've simply misunderstood something or it's a misprint.

[image: page 54]

Comment: Are you considering the effect of R(load) on the output voltage?

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake!  I had connected the load resistor in parallel to the emitter resistor instead of connecting it to ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The emitter and load resistors form a voltage divider for the \$V_{EE}\$ supply. When the transistor goes into cutoff each resistor drops \$5V\$ across them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXgqLw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Becca becca, your circuit shows that I had connected the load resistor incorrectly.  Now it clips at -5v like I would expect.  But why doesn't it clip at -4.4v?

Comment: @nuggethead when the base voltage is -3.8v, the emitter voltage will be -4.4v. Then the emitter supply VEE will be sinking 4.4mA from the load resistor and drawing 1.2mA from the transistor emitter terminal. npn transistor happily allows 1.2mA to go out its emitter terminal, so the transistor wouldn't cutoff and you won't see clipping yet.

Comment: (contd) When the base voltage reaches \$-4.4V\$, the emitter voltage will be \$-5V\$. Now the  voltage across load resistor is \$-5V\$ and the voltage across emitter resistor is \$-5--10=+5V\$. Apply KCL at emitter terminal. \$I_E+5mA-5mA=0 \Rightarrow I_E=0\$ and the transistor is cutoff.